# RecycleView Изменение анимации перемещения

Tags: android, анимация, recycleview

Есть RecycleView с CheckBox при нажатии на него, я сортирую список по отмечено/не отмечено и анимирую его перемещение

```
adapter.notifyItemMoved(position, i);
```

Однако если перемещаю первый элемент за границы текущего экрана список следует за ним, если это не самый верхний элемент, то всё норм. Кто-нибудь встречался с такой проблемой? Есть ли у кого-нибудь пример кастомизации этих методов?

Comment: пример [кастомного ItemAnimator](https://github.com/brijtz/Android_WorkingBeez/blob/594905ea2a198af36ae493d7f6918a8f0ac5ff4e/app/src/main/java/com/app/workingbeez/utils/ItemAnimator.java). Переопределяете нужные методы в нем и все (в вашем случае `animateMove()`)